# SpringMVC/ mockMVC/ jsonpath compare list of strings

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsonpath

I am currently writing some unit tests for a Spring MVC project.
As the returned media type is JSON, I try to use jsonPath to check if the correct values are returned.

The trouble I have is to verify if a list of strings contains the correct (and only the correct) values.

My Plan was:

1. Check that the list has the correct length
2. For each element that's supposed to be returned, check whether it's in the list

sadly, none of these things seem to work.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```java
Collection<AuthorityRole> correctRoles = magicDataSource.getRoles();

ResultActions actions = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/current/roles").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(status().isOk()) // works
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles").isArray()) // works
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles.length").value(correctRoles.size())); // doesn't work

for (AuthorityRole role : correctRoles) // doesn't work
  actions.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles[?(@=='%s')]", role.toString()).exists());
```

Only the first two "expectations" (isOk & isArray) are working. The other ones (for length and content) I can twist and turn however I want, they're not giving me any useful result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

1) Instead of

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles.length").value(correctRoles.size()));
```

try

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles.length()").value(correctRoles.size()));
```

or

```
.andExpect((jsonPath("$.data.roles", Matchers.hasSize(size))));
```

2) Instead of

```
for (AuthorityRole role : correctRoles) // doesn't work
  actions.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles[?(@=='%s')]", role.toString()).exists());
```

try

```
actions.andExpect((jsonPath("$.data.roles", Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("role1", "role2", "role3"))));
```

Keep in mind that you have to add hamcrest-library.

Comment: @chaldaean What hamcrest library are you using? In the one I have, hamcrest-all-1.1, the class org.hamcrest.Matchers does not contain the methods hasSize and containsInAnyOrder.

Comment: This one - hamcrest-library 1.2.1

Comment: For completeness, Hamcrest Matchers can also be added to the value method so andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.roles").value(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(items...)) is just as legal.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I ended up using:

`.andExpect(jsonPath('$.data.roles').value(Matchers.hasSize(size)))`

and

`.andExpect(jsonPath('$.data.roles').value(Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("role1", "role2", "role3")))`