# How to use MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, jsonpath

```
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(mockUrl))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType("application/    json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
```

returns the following:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"version":"0.1"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

However, testing it with

```
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(mockUrl))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType("application/    json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version").value("0.1"))
```

returns the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.version", exception: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI

at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:245)
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$2.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at com.vmware.skyscraper.rts.runbooks.RunbookControllerTest.testGetSingleRunbook(RunbookControllerTest.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

How do I use jsonPath?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the exception? Anyway, looks like you have some extra spaces in `application/json`

Comment: Added the rest of the exception. The extra spaces was a typo in Stackoverflow. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you found the answer to your problem?

Comment: Nope. Not yet. None of the existing suggestions seem to work.

Comment: I'm getting this type of error with Spring Boot 1.5.7

Comment: I had to play around a bit to solve this issue. What worked for me was adding json-smart and net.minidev asm dependencies. `<dependency> <br/>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> `

Comment: This is the dependency  `<dependency> <groupId>net.minidev</groupId> <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId> <version>2.3</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>net.minidev</groupId> <artifactId>asm</artifactId> <version>1.0.2</version> <scope>test</scope>`

Answer (score 35):

I think you need to pass the Matcher to the `jsonPath` method.  For example.

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.version", is("0.1")))
```

References:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#jsonPath(java.lang.String,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-write-clean-assertions-with-jsonpath/

[SpringMVC/ mockMVC/ jsonpath compare list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371022/springmvc-mockmvc-jsonpath-compare-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 21):

Your code works for me just fine. I am using Jackson to parse the cases and that's probably the only difference. Check my code:

Result class:

```
public class Res {
    String version;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blah",
        method = GET,
        produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<Res> doIt() {
    Res res = new Res();
    res.setVersion("0.1");
    return new HttpEntity<>(res);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void blahTest() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/blah"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.version").value("0.1"))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
}
```

Response:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"version":"0.1"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I can only recommend trying to change the Json parser library you are using. Otherwise, try to update your code with all the parts that are needed to create a simple, minimal and reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how you are using Jackson. My understanding was that Res object was implicitly getting converted to Json. How can we explicitly convert to json using Jackson?

Comment: I use spring boot, jackson is the standard library that provides the conversion. It is automatically added by spring-boot-starter-web I think.

Answer (score 2):

All credit for this answer goes to @pramodh (Hidden in OP's comments)

I had the exact same problem and installing his reccomended dependencies fixed everything.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```